# VBA code to complement search keyword on worksheet with copy rows selected to new worksheet

Tags: vba

The code below basically searches for any keyword in any sheet and highlights it. My question is, how to also copy the entire row number where the word/words is/are found to a new sheet in addition to the highlight?

Is it also possible to precise in which worksheet the search will be done?

Many thanks in advance,
Gonzalo

```
Sub CheckMULTIVALUE()

'This macro searches the entire workbook for any cells containing the text "#MULTIVALUE" and if found _
highlight the cell(s) in yellow. Once the process has completed a message box will appear confirming completion.

Dim i As Long
Dim Fnd As String
Dim fCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Fnd = InputBox("Find what:", "Find and Highlight", "#MULTIVALUE")
If Fnd = "" Then Exit Sub

For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        Set fCell = .Range("A1")
        For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, Fnd)
            Set fCell = .Cells.Find(What:=Fnd, After:=fCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            If fCell Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox Fnd & " not on sheet !!"
                Exit For
            Else
                With fCell
                     .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    End With
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Check complete"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add code before the `For` loop to create the results worksheet or clear it if it already exists:

```
Dim results As Worksheet: Set results = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Results")

If results Is Nothing Then
    Set results = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add()
    results.Name = "Results"
Else
    results.Cells.Clear
End If
```

Create a reference to its `A1` cell and a counter:

```
Dim resultsRange As Range: Set resultsRange = results.Range("A1")
Dim matches As Long
```

When you find a match add what you need to the Results worksheet and increment the counter.

```
With fCell
     .Interior.ColorIndex = 6

     resultsRange.Offset(matches, 0).Value = fCell.Row
     resultsRange.Offset(matches, 1).Value = fCell.Value
     matches = matches + 1
End With
```

To specify a specific sheet remove `For Each ws In Worksheets` and `Next ws` and replace `With ws` with `With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetNameHere")`

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment @Alex - your code worked like charm, thanks!